# Check If FILE is OPEN or NOT

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

I am working in `MS Words` `Rough.doc` file and I want to check if `Ceemea & Latam.doc` File is open or not. There should be two possible output.

**1. If already opened then `Activate`**

**2. If not, then open `Ceemea & Latam`**

Using following code but it returning `compile error`

```
If AlreadyOpen("C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\EMEA CEEMEA\CEEMEA & LATAM.doc") Then

    Windows("CEEMEA & LATAM").Activate

Else

    Documents.Open FileName:="C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\EMEA CEEMEA\CEEMEA & LATAM.doc"

End If
```

Comment: So you thought that since you need an `AlreadyOpen` function, there must be one, and you just tried to use it, hoping you get the name right, and then it surprises you there is an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sub ActivateOrOpen()
    on error goto nofile
    Windows("CEEMEA & LATAM").Activate
    exit sub

    nofile:
    Documents.Open FileName:="C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\EMEA CEEMEA\CEEMEA & LATAM.doc"
end sub
```

Comment: Is there any possibility of using `if then else` for this kind of situation?

Comment: You can move the `on error goto` part to another function that would capture it and return `true` or `false`, but it'll be no different. You will have to handle the exception somewhere anyway.

Answer (score 2):

try this function:

```
Function AlreadyOpen(filePath As String) As Boolean
Dim result As Boolean
result = False
For Each aDoc In Documents
 apath = aDoc.Path + "\" + aDoc.Name
 If apath = filePath Then result = True
Next aDoc
AlreadyOpen = result
End Function
```

Comment: this gives me a "type mismatch" error on line `For Each aDoc In Documents`
I wonder how it is possible at all to have a type mismach on a line that defines a foreach loop, but VBA never ceases to amaze me.